# If the Domain of $f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x^2+5x+6}$= all real numbers except $-3$ and $-2$, why does $f(x)=\frac{2}{x^2 +3}$= all real numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry, I'm just at around 20% Algebra 1 and this doesn't make sense to me so. 
Obviously, you can't divide by $0$ but wouldn't $f(x)=\frac{2}{x^2+3}$ also mean that $x^2 = -3$, which would also mean that the domain should be all real numbers BUT $-3$?

Comment: $x^2+3$ is always at least 3, so it can't be zero. On the other hand, $x^2+5x+6$  factors as $(x+2)(x+3)$ so the denominator is zero (bad!) when $x=-2$ or $x=-3$.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please use Mathjax :)

Comment: $(-3)^2+3=9+3=12$ also $(-\sqrt{3})^2+3=3+3=6$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that if the denominator is zero, that's a problem. You've writeen $x = -3$, but I think you meant $x^2 = -3$, since then $x^2 + 3$ would be $0$.

But since $x^2$ is always nonnegative, $x = -3$ is not really a problem.

Alternatively, maybe you read $x^2 + 3$ as "take $x$, add $3$, and then square it". But what it means is "take $x$, square it, and add $3$." To get the first thing, you write $(x + 3)^2$.